# iphone:In view based application how can I move from 4th screen to 1st screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am creating view based application and in this application I want to directly switch over to 1st screen from 4th screen then how can I do this?

My code to go to next view is as follows:

```
NewProposalDetail *newDetail = [[NewProposalDetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewProposalDetail" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:newDetail animated:YES];
    [newDetail release];
```

Any idea?
if yes then share it

Answer (score 1):

The same way you switch screens using `pushViewControllers` and `popViewControllers` to any other screen. Use

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The first view is the root view you see so simply put this line and it will pick up the firstView.

Comment: my app is model based application

Comment: Are the number of modal views fixed?

Comment: Is you want you can directly call the presentModalViewController : First in the 4th View . But if you want to dismiss each and every view  to go to the first view then you will have to create a global variable that will be assigned a different value in each view and in the 4th view you can put if conditions ....